# How do I solve X is 7 or more greater than Y

Tags: javascript

**How do i solve this problem:**

if X is 7 or more greater than Y in javascript show green.

if X if from 4-7 greater than Y show blue.

else show red

this is what i have tried so far:

```
function solve (x,y) {
            if(x > (y +7) ){
                return "green"
            }

            else {
                return "red";
            }
```

}

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: If that is your full javascript code block then you're missing a closing curly brace for the function.

Comment: @Quentin am getting undefined

Comment: @melkisadek i know i haven't posted the whole thing but the problem is in this part of it

Comment: Where are you getting undefined? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because that function isn't closed

By the way you can't say something ISN'T WORKING if you don't provide the complete code that doesn't work and the error

Anyway

The right code would be

```
    function solve (x,y) {
            if(x >= (y +7) ){
                return "green"
            }

            else {
                return "blue";
            }
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.